# how to put an @string resource in a specific code?

Tags: java, android, string

how can I make an @string ressource instead of a text value for MY_TEXT? I want it to use for different languages.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == R.drawable.v1)textView.setText("MY_TEXT");
else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v2)textView.setText("MY_TEXT2");
```

Comment: getResources().getString(R.string.mess_1);

Use this to get text from string.xml

Comment: If you want multi-language support refer to this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.mytext));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getResources().getString(int id)`

Example:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == R.drawable.v1)
        textView.setText(getResources().getString(
                    R.string.mystr));
    else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v2)
        textView.setText(getResources().getString(
                    R.string.somestr));  
}
```

Add String values in, `res/values/strings.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="mystr"> your text</string>
    <string name="somestr"> some other text</string>
</resources>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support different languages, you should provide different "values" folders for different languages then put your strings.xml files in those folders. Like this:

```
 project_root/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-de/
           strings.xml
```

Here "es" is ISO language code for Spanish, "de" for German and so on. You'll find a complete list at [List of ISO 639-1 codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes).

Then, when referencing them in code, just use the normal *R.string.my_string_name*. Depending on the device's locality settings, it will pick the available language file. It will pick the default if a needed language file does not exist.